# Nginx: proxy pass with basic http auth and excluding some files

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to exclude some files from http auth (Brightcove video upload fix in Drupal), but my nginx configuration doesn't work properly:

```
location / {
auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

location ~* \.(3g2|3gp|asf|avi|dv|flv|f4v|m4v|mov|mp4|mpeg|mpg|mts|m2ts|qt|wmv|jpg|png|jpeg)$ {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
}

proxy_set_header Authorization  "";
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_pass $ip;
}
```

Http auth is working, proxy pass is working but I'm still not able to upload Brightcove videos. Similar config for another server with apache worked fine:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /etc/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI \.(3g2|3gp|asf|avi|dv|flv|f4v|m4v|mov|mp4|mpeg|mpg|mts|m2ts|qt|wmv|jpg|png|jpeg)$ allow
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

Does anyone can help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Move location `location ~* \.(3g2|3gp|asf|avi|dv|flv|f4v|m4v|mov|mp4|mpeg|mpg|mts|m2ts|qt|wmv|jpg|png|jpeg)$` out of the root location and it should work.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked fine:

```
location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    proxy_set_header Authorization  "";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass $ip;
}

location ~* \.(3g2|3gp|asf|avi|dv|flv|f4v|m4v|mov|mp4|mpeg|mpg|mts|m2ts|qt|wmv|jpg|png|jpeg)$ {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
    proxy_set_header Authorization  "";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass $ip;
}
```

I tested this config before, but didn't know that Brightcove videos need some time to start playing :-)